# Выход за пределы

Tags: python, list, index

```
n = int(input())
a = [[0]*n, [0, 0]]
for i in range(0, n):
    x, y = map(int, input().split())
    a[i][0] = x
    a[i][1] = y
```

a[i][0] = x
IndexError: list index out of range
Почему появляется такая ошибка?
Как ее можно исправить. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Потому что в списке a всегда ровно 2 элемента, очевидно

Comment: Но, если я правильно понимаю, то а у меня двумерный список, состоящий из n строк в каждой из которых 2 элемента? Или я неправильно объявил. Просто питон для меня в новинку.

Comment: У вас список из двух элементов, в первом элементе список из n нулей, во втором - список из двух нулей. Всё по порядку как в коде через запятую написано

Comment: тогда я правильно понимаю, что для объявления двумерного списка из n строк по два элемента в каждой нужно сделать так: a = [[0] * 2] * n ?

Comment: Логика рассуждений правильная, но это не будет работать, так как вот такое умножение списка не создаёт копию внутренних элементов, и в итоге внутри будет не n списков с двумя нулями, а один-единственный список с двумя нулями, просто повторённый n раз. Придётся неизбежно писать цикл с a.append([0] * 2)

Answer (score 0):

используйте массив. Изучите попутно основы модуля numpy:

```
import numpy as np
n = int(input())
a = np.zeros((2,n), dtype=np.int)
for i in range(0, n):
    x, y = map(int, input().split())
    a[i][0] = x
    a[i][1] = y
```

код `a = np.zeros((2,n))` как раз создает нужный вам массив с нулями

Answer (score 0):

У Вас список из массивов. Чтобы сделать двумерный массив (без подключения модуля numPy, как было предложено ранее), воспользуйтесь генератором:

```
a = [[0, 0] for i in range(n + 1)]
```

Тогда у Вас будет n + 1 элементов (массивов [0, 0]) в массиве и ошибка с индексом пропадет.